# Can this be represented as $f:x\to y$? Its inverse function?

Tags: functions

$$y+5x+6x^4y=0$$

What will be the inverse function of this quartic equation?

Comment: Equations don't have inverses, operations/functions do. The equation $x-4=0$ has a solution ($x=4$), but no inverse. The operation $x \mapsto x-4$ has an inverse, namely $x \mapsto x+4$.

Comment: Perhaps you can express $y$ as a function of $x$, but you wanted to express $x$ as a function of $y$?  The equation does neither of these explicitly, and being able to do one function is no guarantee that the other function (as a full inverse) will necessarily exist.

Comment: thanks for the correction up there. if you express this equation as a function of x, one will get unique values of y. Hence, it can be represented as f: x-->y. But how do I express this function's inverse?

Comment: @Vans Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

$x$ as a function of $y$ is a root of a polynomial of degree $4$.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solution_methods) you can find some general methods to compute those roots.

Note: Be aware, that if you are studying calculus, there are many properties of inverse functions/ implicit functions that can be determined without computing the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. There are four such functions $y:x\mapsto y(x)$, each one defined differently according to the four possible solutions to your equation. The closed forms of these functions are quite nasty, check this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=isolate(y%2B5x%2B6x4y%3D0,y)

What you can do if you want to study the behavior of these functions rather than having closed forms is to take implicit derivatives and study them.

Answer (score 0):

Note that since

- $y(0)=0$ and $x\to \infty \quad y(x)\to 0$

by EVT $y(x)$ is not injective and thus it is not invertible over  the whole domain.

The inverse exist for those restrictions with $y(x):[a,b]\to[c,d]$ bijective.